# Translated content field labels are showing in the original language in the node page in Drupal 8, How can I display the translated labels instead?

Tags: drupal, localization, drupal-8

I have a Drupal 8 multilingual website,
when I translate labels for a content types fields, and I set the labels to be shown in the *Manage display* options , It's shown in the original language!!

I'm using bootstrap sub-theme and the used field template `field.html.twig` has the next code to display the label:

```
<div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label }}</div>
```

and in the core file `\core\includes\theme.inc` the `preprocess_field` hook has this code:

```
function template_preprocess_field(&$variables, $hook) {
  ...
  $variables['label'] = $element['#title'];
  ...
}
```

have I missed something? any idea how can I display the translated labels?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
<div{{ title_attributes.addClass(title_classes) }}>{{ label|t }}</div>
```